# wpf setting datatable as itemsource get list but isn't visible

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatable, rows, itemsource

DataGrid1.ItemsSource = mgr.srcData(0).DefaultView 'returns datatable

DataGrid1 has all the columns hidden but only 2 visibles

Running the application works, appear the rows but doesn't show the values, only blank rows although I can get their values

onclick -> gets value as datarowview and after I get the first element/field ---> Ok tested

Comment: Can you show your xaml `DataTemplate`

Comment: <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="165" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,121,0,0" Name="DataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="227" BorderBrush="White" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" Foreground="Black" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" IsEnabled="True" HeadersVisibility="Column" EnableRowVirtualization="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="False" IsReadOnly="True" FontStyle="Oblique" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFC4A6A6" FontWeight="SemiBold">

Comment: <DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="idpers" Visibility="Hidden" Foreground="#FFFFF8F8" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="cognoms" Foreground="#FF7C7C7C" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding}" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="nom" Foreground="#FF7C7C7C" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGrid.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FFCF9797" Offset="1" />
   </LinearGradientBrush>
  </DataGrid.Background>
 </DataGrid>